# What should an async method do if a Task is conditionally executed?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Suppose I have a method that awaits a Task. This method also returns a Task. For example:

```
public async virtual Task Save(String path)
{
    if (NewWords.Any())
    {
        await FileManager.WriteDictionary(path, NewWords, true);
    }
    else await Task.Run(() => { });
}
```

Is the

```
else await Task.Run(() => { });
```

necessary here or am I free to leave it? Is there any difference if it is present/absent? Maybe there is some other approach to this I should take?

Comment: Tell us why you inserted that code. It's not necessary and it's evidence that you must misunderstand something. Need to find out what it is.

Comment: It's not necessary, and it's also harmful.

Comment: DONT USE `Task.Run` IN IMPLEMENTATION! http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worse than unnecessary, as you're spinning up a thread to do nothing and then waiting until after its finished doing nothing.

The simplest way to do nothing, is to do nothing. In an `async` method the method will still have returned a `Task`, but that `Task` will be completed already, so something `await`ing it further up will get straight onto the next thing it needs to do:

```
public async virtual Task Save(String path)
{
    if (NewWords.Any())
    {
        await FileManager.WriteDictionary(path, NewWords, true);
    }
}
```

(Also, it would be more in line with convention if `SaveAsync` and `WriteDictionaryAsync` were the method names here).
If not using `async` (and there's no need to here, but I understand it's an example) use `Task.CompletedTask`:

```
public virtual Task Save(String path)
{
    if (NewWords.Any())
    {
        return FileManager.WriteDictionary(path, NewWords, true);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If you are coding against an earlier framework than 4.6 and therefore don't have `CompletedTask` available, then `Task.Delay(0)` is useful as `Delay` special cases the value `0` to return a cached completed task (in fact, the same one that `CompletedTask` returns):

```
public virtual Task Save(String path)
{
    if (NewWords.Any())
    {
        return FileManager.WriteDictionary(path, NewWords, true);
    }
    return Task.Delay(0);
}
```

But the 4.6 way is clearer as to your intent, rather than depending on a quirk of implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, that helped me clean this up. I was a bit puzzled about the compiler allowing me not to return anything on some code path (despite being aware of that Task is the result of a background operation returning void). I guess the compiler treats it uniquely just like it does void, right?

Comment: Pretty much. The point of `async` is to let us write methods that return tasks with potentially pretty complicated sequences of waiting on other tasks, much as we would write the equivalent synchronous method. So just as a synchronous method that does nothing can be empty (or empty in a given branch) so can an `async` that just returns a completed task. What actually happens is that a state machine is created and similar to how `yield` is turned into `MoveNext()` so this has a `MoveNext()` that is called into once at the beginning and then after every task you've `await`ed returns...

Comment: ... in the case of following a path that didn't hit an `await` then the first call into that `MoveNext()` indicates that is done. The `Task` that uses that state machine (which is what your method really returns) is then put into a completed state. Since the first `MoveNext()` happens before the `Task` is completed (and indeed any others if all the `await`s hit on completed tasks and don't have to actually wait) then the task is completed already when returned.

Answer (score 5):

It's not neccesary. The `async` is only needed if at least one `await` is used. Everything inside the method is executed synchronously except for the `await` part.